# How to lock whole sheets, columns or rows in Excel based on values in a Table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a table that allows locking/protecting of specific sheets, columns or rows in a workbook based on values in the "LockSheets" Table.

Here is the LockSheets Table:
[image: The LockSheets Table]

So the column names and row names which should be locked/protected from user editing are listed as comma-separated values in the LockedCols and LockedRows columns of the Table.

```
Sub LockCols()  Dim ls As ListObject
    Dim lSheetNames As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ls = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(“Controls”).ListObjects(“LockSheets”)
    Set lSheetNames = ls.ListColumns(“Sheets”).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    For Each sheetName In lSheetNames
        ‘locking whole sheets loop’
        If sheetName.Offset(,1).value = True Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName.value.Protect
            Debug.Print “Locking” & sheetName
        End If

        ‘locking whole columns loop;
        If sheetName.Offset(,2).value <> “” Then
            sheetLockedCols = Split(sheetName.Offset(,2).value,”,”)
            col = Trim(col)
            For each col in sheetLockedCols
                colT = Trim(col) ’trim for any whitespace’
                Set cell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName.value).Columns(colT)
                cell.Cells.Locked = True
            Next col
        End If

        ‘locking whole columns loop’

    Next sheetName
End Sub
```

The 'locking whole sheets loop' works as intended. But I cannot get locking individual columns to lock any of the sheet, although the debug prints confirms that it has read the column names as intended. I haven't written the lock rows loop as I assume it would fail for the same reason as my columns loop.

Comment: `sheetName.Offset(, 3)` returns column `lockedRows` not `lockedColumns`! Furthermore you should first lock the cells and then apply the sheet protection - the current code will throw an error when setting cell.locked = true

Comment: sorry, realised that typo shortly after posting. I don't quite understand the distinction between locking and protecting them? If I want users to be able to edit the rest of the sheet, should it be protected or unprotected?

Answer (score 1):

`Range.Locked` indicates if the object (cells / range) is locked. All cells has `Locked=True` by default.

> [Range.Locked property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.locked?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

`Worksheet.Protect` protects a worksheet so that it cannot be modified. It only protects all cells which have `Locked=True`. That is, users can edit the unprotect cells (`Locked=False`) on a protected worksheet.

> [Worksheet.Protect method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```vb
Sub LockColsRow()
    Dim ls As ListObject
    Dim lSheetNames As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngShtName, vItem, sheetLockedCols, sheetLockedRows
    Set ls = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Controls").ListObjects("LockSheets")
    Set lSheetNames = ls.ListColumns("Sheets").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    For Each rngShtName In lSheetNames
        'locking whole sheets loop'
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(rngShtName.Value)
            ws.Unprotect
            ws.Cells.Locked = False
        If rngShtName.Offset(, 1).Value = True Then
            'locking whole columns loop;
            If rngShtName.Offset(, 2).Value <> "" Then
                sheetLockedCols = Split(rngShtName.Offset(, 2).Value, ",")
                For Each vItem In sheetLockedCols
                    ws.Columns(Trim(vItem)).Cells.Locked = True
                Next vItem
            End If
            'locking whole rows loop;
            If rngShtName.Offset(, 3).Value <> "" Then
                sheetLockedRows = Split(rngShtName.Offset(, 3).Value, ",")
                For Each vItem In sheetLockedRows
                    ws.Rows(Trim(vItem)).Cells.Locked = True
                Next vItem
            End If
            ws.Protect
            Debug.Print "Locking" & rngShtName
        End If
    Next rngShtName
End Sub
```

Comment: More precise: `Range.Locked` indicates that the object (cells / range) will be locked **when the worksheet becomes protected**. If the worksheet is not protected `Range.locked` has no effect.